# Can't run a Tampermonkey script on the Google Trends Page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tampermonkey, google-trends

I'm using the Chrome browser with the Tampermonkey extension. I need to write a script that can run on the Google Trends page, but after several trials and errors, I still can't get it work.

My code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       run on google trends page 
// @namespace  http://use.i.E.your.googleTrends.com
// @version    0.1
// @description  I'm trying to get this script work,please help.
// @match     https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=apple
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js
// @copyright  2012+, You
// ==/UserScript==

$(document).ready(function(){

    alert("This script works!");
});
```

Comment: Your `@match` was incorrect. Just change it to `@include https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=apple*` no need to muck about with a full extension.

Comment: I was using Tampermonkey, but working on a full extension is so much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to convert it to a Google Chrome Extension.

You need a:

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "run on google trends page",
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "I'm trying to get this script work,please help.",
    "homepage_url": "http://use.i.E.your.googleTrends.com",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://www.google.com/*"
            ],
            "include_globs":[
                "*google.com/trends/explore#q=apple*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "jquery-2.1.1.min.js",
                "script.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("This script works!");
});
```

And done, working :)

Load it as unpacked extension from the extension tab in Google Chrome.

Comment: The result is exactly what I wanted to get, DarkThanos, thank you sooooo much for your quick response and great solution to my problem.